# Programmatically run cypress tests on docker

Tags: cypress

I am currently running cypress tests using:

`await cypress.run({config inserted here})`

Wondering if there is a way to spin up one of cypress's docker containers and then point the cypress tests there using the statement above. The suggestions online are to run the tests using command line, but I'm hoping to still be able to use `cypress.run()` and perhaps pass in an option that tells cypress to point the tests to a container?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress docker containers will invoke `cypress run` by default. To change that, you'll need to override the container entrypoint to invoke node instead of cypress, and then pass your script file that's invoking cypress via the module api (`cypress.run()`) as the container command. You could do this [via the command line](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command#Commands-and-options), but it's a bit long because of all the options you'll need to pass:

```sh
# Assumes you're running this from the Cypress project directory on the host machine
$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/tests -w /tests --entrypoint "/usr/local/bin/node" cypress/included:3.2.0 "myScript.js"
```

Warning: you're mounting in your npm dependencies with this method, which might cause problems if any of them were compiled on a different os like Windows.

Comment: with selenium I start one of selenium's docker contains e.g. via `docker run ....` Then in the code, I point driver to the server e.g. `new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(<insert capabilities here>).usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")` Is there a similar workflow with cypress? e.g. start some container (if so which one), then in the code somewhere, tell the tests to run on that container, perhaps via one of the options in the `cypress.run()` command (if so, which option). Would be grateful if you could show an example of this workflow if it is possible with cypress